# how to merge Image and videoBrush in one image in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-7

how to merge Image and videoBrush in one image in windows phone 7?

For example there is the code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="viewfinderCanvas" Width="640" Height="480" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            <Canvas.Background>
                <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush" />
            </Canvas.Background>
            <Image source="myImage.png"/>
        </Canvas>
```

If for example I add a picture in the `Image` - Logo with transparent background, and I want to when you click the "Make a photo" logo remained on the photo.

Image from the camera to take with the help of:

```
PhotoCamera cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
```

How to make it so that when you save a photo on it was applied to a picture of the Image (my logo)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft have a full flexed example of how to do overlays on a VideoBrush, see MSDN: [How to: Work with Grayscale in a Camera Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202982%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

To merge two images, use the `Blit` method from the [WriteBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) project.

Comment: in a different way. I need a picture taken with the camera to put a picture of the Image, and then save it in a single file in media library

Comment: Not really what you posted code for. I updated my answer with a way to merge two `BitmapImage`